# copiar el valor de una columna a otra dependiendo de una condicion

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, databricks

estoy intentando copiar el valor de una columna a otra, dependiendo de una  condición
Mi dataframe se llama histórico
Este es el dataframe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi línea de codigo:

```
historico.loc[historico["A"]=="DIRECTO","NuevaColumna"]=historico[["B"]]
historico.loc[historico["A"]!="DIRECTO","NuevaColumna"]=historico[["A"]]
```

quiero que si la columna “A” es igual a DIRECTO me traiga en una nueva columna los nombres de B
y si es diferente a DIRECTO que me traiga   en la nueva columna  los nombres de  A.
desde ya gracias ¡!

Answer (score 0):

Podés usar [pandas.Series.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html). El método where recibe una condición. Si la condición devuelve verdadero, agrega a la nueva serie el valor original. En cambio, si devuelve falso, toma el valor correspondiente del segundo argumento pasado (en este caso, la columna b).

###### Código

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=["juan", "DIRECTO", "francisco", "fernando", "DIRECTO"],
                       b=["rodrigo", "pepe", "lucas", "tito", "felipe"]))

print("Antes...")
print(df)
print()
df["c"] = df["a"].where(df["a"] != "DIRECTO", df["b"], axis=0)
print("Después...")
print(df)
```

###### Produce

```
Antes...
           a        b
0       juan  rodrigo
1    DIRECTO     pepe
2  francisco    lucas
3   fernando     tito
4    DIRECTO   felipe

Después...
           a        b          c
0       juan  rodrigo       juan
1    DIRECTO     pepe       pepe
2  francisco    lucas  francisco
3   fernando     tito   fernando
4    DIRECTO   felipe     felipe
```